# Using grep with pipe and ampersand to filter errors from find

Tags: bash, command-line, find, grep

I am using cygwin to find a file on the cygdrive.

However I need to suppress the permission denied messages (otherwise the results get hidden in the error messages). The following command works:

```
find -name 'myfile.*' |& grep -v "Permission denied"
```

I don't understand why the ampersand needs to be put into this command, would have expected this to work but it doesn't.

```
find -name 'myfile.*' | grep -v "Permission denied"
```

Please explain the meaning of the ampersand.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In Unix-like systems, there are two output paths that if left unmodified will send output to your screen. Standard error (or stderr) is the one that captures most failures and error conditions.

To pass the permission denied message in the stderr to the same output stream as "regular output" you must combine the two. In your example, in order for your `grep -v` to properly operate on it, you combine stdout (standard output) and stderr with the arcane syntax you see.

From [GNU Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) section [3.2.2 Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html):

> If ‘`|&`’ is used, *command1*’s standard error, in addition to its
>   standard output, is connected to *command2*’s standard input through
>   the pipe; it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`. This implicit redirection of
>   the standard error to the standard output is performed after any
>   redirections specified by the command.

Also, as geirha points out, if you want to just get rid of stderr output, you would want to do something like

```
find -name 'myfile.*' 2> /dev/null
```

or perhaps

```
find -name 'myfile.*' 2> /tmp/errorlog
```

And note that if you have strings of commands, such as a `find` passing its output to `xargs` you would need to put the entire pipeline of commands in parentheses to capture the output from all components of the command. E.g.,

```
(find | egrep ^[RS].[0-9]+/.svg] | xargs head -1 )  2> /dev/null
```

If you left out the parentheses, and did this instead --

```
find | egrep ^[RS].[0-9]+/.svg] | xargs head -1 2> /dev/null
```

you would still see permission denied errors from the find or egrep, but stderr would be redirected for xargs.

As you've seen, you would likely throw away the stderr only after viewing its contents during a test run.

Note that with GNU `find` and as far as I can tell, any POSIX-compliant `find`, the `-print` option is implicit. You can still supply it explicitly if you like.

Comment: Seems to be only bash4+ http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/bash4#redirection

Comment: @LukeExton Yes. In other shells, `2>&1 |` may be used in place of `|&` (i.e., one can explicitly redirect stderr to stdout and then pipe that to the next command in the pipeline).

Comment: `2> >( grep filter )` is also handy

Answer (score 13):

Error messages are written to [*stderr*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29), not [*stdout*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stderr#Standard_output_.28stdout.29), but `|` pipes only *stdout*.

You probably want `|&`, [which pipes *stderr* as well as *stdout*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ignore the error messages, just redirect stderr to /dev/null.

```
find . -name 'myfile.*' -print 2>/dev/null
```

Also, consider reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind.