# Search and print the lines from the output which can contain lines with errors

Tags: command-line, scripts, grep

I have a command example,

```
device list
```

which gives me all devices with their **status** as *okay or error* in the following format

```
[okay     ]:  you are listening on : 11
[error    ]:  not currently listening: 22
[error    ]:  not currently listening: 33
[okay     ]:  you are listening on : 111
```

I want to print only devices that has status as *okay*.

I tried using *grep* command as

```
device list | grep -r 'okay'
device list | grep -r '[okay     ]'
device list | grep -r '^okay'
device list | grep  'okay'
```

But it didn't print any output.
How can I print the devices with status as *okay.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use `-r` option with `grep` in this case, because (look at `man grep`):

> ```
> -r, --recursive
>               Read all files  under  each  directory,  recursively,  following
>               symbolic  links  only  if they are on the command line.  This is
>               equivalent to the -d recurse option.
> ```

You also have to redirect and errors from the standard output to be piped by the `grep` command using [`2>&1`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/818255/2353900) redirection:

```
device list 2>&1 | grep 'okay'
```

Or you can use [`|&`](https://askubuntu.com/q/24953/147044):

```
device list |& grep 'okay'
```

Answer (score 2):

From the output given to us, at least the version of the `grep` should have been able to work.
If it doesn't, the only possible reason is because this command doesn't print its output on `STDOUT` but on `STDERR`.
Both are displayed on any terminal/console by default, but commands like `grep` when takin its input via a pipe (`|`) do this from `STDOUT` only.

The solution is to redirect the output of `STDERR` to `STDOUT`, this is what the `2>&1` or `|&` will do :

```
$ device list 2>&1 | grep okay
$ device list |& grep okay
```

The 3 first forms of your command, using `grep -r` will never works, even if you redirect the output of `STDERR` because the `-r` option is used to recurse into directory and subdirectory. So even if used after a pipe, `grep -r something` will search something in files in all directories from where you run the command.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `-r` option of your grep command and it will work:

```
device list | grep 'okay'
```

`-r` is for recursive search.