# Retrieve the first few lines from testing result with head -n

Tags: bash, python3

I am testing a python program and desire to retrieve its first two lines of results

```
$ python twoSum.py  
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 find: 151 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 find: 194 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 find: 247 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 find: 192 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 find: 206 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 find: 171 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 find: 170 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 find: 190 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 find: 132 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31921-MainThread:140190102726464 j: 63
[8, 63]
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Employ `head` to tackle the text

```
$ python twoSum.py  | head -n 1
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 find: 259 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 find: 235 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 find: 133 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 find: 274 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 find: 265 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 find: 257 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 find: 280 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 find: 134 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 find: 138 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 j: None
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 find: 145 
DEBUG-MainProcess:31978-MainThread:140699277834048 j: 75
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
```

It does not work,
How could I retrieve the first few lines which I want to see.

Comment: could you please transmit the comment to answer. @steeldriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the `DEBUG-` outputs are going to the standard error stream rather than the standard output stream - try

```
python twoSum.py 2>&1 | head -n 1
```

to redirect `stderr` (file descriptor #2) to `stdout` (file descriptor #1); or (bash shorthand)

```
python twoSum.py |& head -n 1
```

For further information see the related question [Using grep with pipe and ampersand to filter errors from find](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24953/using-grep-with-pipe-and-ampersand-to-filter-errors-from-find).